# Team member deleted from the google developer account

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-account

I am license owner in google developer account.I have invited some team members to join this developer program. One of the team member has admin role permission and he published an android app on play store on behalf of our group.
  What would happen if i delete that user from the team. Who will get the whole rights of published app by that user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The admin always has the access. If you delete him, you get the access right.